# How to display column value based on frequency value of another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where row 'code' is populated with codes, and row 'note' is populated with notes. Since the codes mean something I want to count their frequencies. E.g. with .value_counts(), and then I also want to know what note is attached to anyone of the unique codes.

For example, the code A has at one of the rows, the note 'adam'. Now I want to count how many A there is, and display one of the notes to anyone of the A's. (I don't want to count each code seperately, but to show the frequency for all codes at once)

Example:

```
IN:
code  note
A     adam
A     august
A     abdul
B     bree
B     bar
A     august
B     barnie
B     barnie
C     ceasar
C     coolio
A     august
```

```
OUT:
A     5     adam
B     4     bree
C     2     ceasar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `agg` with two aggfuncs - `count`, and `first`:

```
df.groupby('code').note.agg(['count', 'first'])

      count   first
code               
A         5    adam
B         4    bree
C         2  ceasar
```

Comment: And how to sort them by descending count?

Comment: @AnonX Use `sort_values`: `df.groupby('code').note.agg(['count', 'first']).sort_values('count', ascending=False)`